# automatic update database of android application

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm making an quiz application in android.
But If there are changes in database then how can user get updated with this changes.
I read about GCM and php.
But can anyone tell me how to do that?
Any helpful tutorial?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCM is used to notify your app that it needs to update. It can then start a service and download the file in the background, or set preference flag and ask the user if they want to update the next time they start the app. It is only a trigger, you have to implement the actual update in your app. There is no need to use PHP or create a dynamic website, just put the file somewhere so that the app can download it.